# Remove Snap Back in OwlCarousel when using SinglePage setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

Currently I am experiencing a snap back from the last image to the first when OwlCarousel reaches the last image. I would prefare it to continuously repeat in the same direction.

Is there a setting for this?

Currently the code is:

```
g.owlCarousel({
    navigation: false,
    slideSpeed: 500,
    items: 1,
    pagination: false,
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: false,
    touchDrag: false,
    autoPlay: true,
    singleItem: true
});
```

Comment: hi, you can use rewindNav:false

Comment: for continuous you can use 'loop:true'